# Like operator not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

I have a problem about searching in PHP.
I can't get the datas from database that I search for,
and I can't find any problem in the codes.
Info: Both codes are in the same page.

HTML:

```
<form action="articles.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="..." class="form-control">
  <button type="submit" name="search_for_article_admincp" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['search_for_article_admincp'])) {
    $search = trim($_POST['search']);
    $search_for_article_admincp=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE name LIKE :search OR content LIKE :search LIMIT $display,$limit");
    $search_for_article_admincp->bindValue("search","%search%",PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $search_for_article_admincp->execute(); $list = $search_for_article_admincp->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($list as $article) { ?> 
        DATAS / HTML CONTENT 
        <?php 
     } 
}
```

?>

Comment: Anything in your error log? Where is $list being defined in your foreach loop?

Comment: `$search_for_article_admincp->bindValue("search","%search%",PDO::PARAM_STR);` this looks incorrect to me? Shouldn't this be something like: `bindValue(":search",$search,PDO::PARAM_STR);` ?

Comment: @IsThisJavascript Thank you very much... It solved

Comment: You're missing `$` in `"%search%"`.

Comment: have you tried => SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE name LIKE :search OR content LIKE :search LIMIT $display,$limit on database, is this return any data?

Comment: You have missed $ in %search%